# My htaccess file doesnt want recongnise my code

Tags: php, server-side

it doesnt work, i tried a lot of variations.

it should work like:
https://example.com/XXXXX/XX.XXX.XX.X
result in:
https://example.com/verifyIP.php?verify=XX.XXX.XX.X&token=XXXX

My .htaaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^check/(.*)/(.*)$ checkIP.php?verify=$1&token=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What does happen instead?

Comment: `checkIP.php?verify=$1&token=$2` would need to be `checkIP.php?verify=$2&token=$1` according to your example anyway if that was to work as intended

Comment: 1. File not found, but its in my root location.

Comment: 2. This is an Example to order the Vars yet.

Comment: checkIP.php vs. verifyIP.php?

Answer (score 0):

1. File not found, but its in my root location.
2. This is an Example to order the Vars yet.

Comment: To add something to your question, you should [edit] it instead of posting an answer.